# Python 3 urlopen command - later code not run

Tags: python-3.x, url, node-red

Like many people, I find solutions to issues online and implement without any real understanding. This is one of those.

My python script is kicking off a nodered flow, by using urlopen to send a start command. The flow is triggering correctly on this http-in "start" so that part is great.

However, the way I have written it is not continuing with the later code. I would expect to see the "time.sleep(180)" text but nothing else happens. The code snippet is below with the console print lines:

```
    print("kick off node red")
    urlopen("http://localhost:1880/start").read()
    print("time.sleep(180)")
    time.sleep(180)
```

`kick off node red`

I guess it is awaiting some response but not sure what that would be in the nodered flow and also, what the python code should be to continue. I know this is my basic lack of understanding of url calls but I would be grateful for help.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74097824/edit) to show an image of your Node-RED flow. (I have an idea as to what the problem is and this is the quickest way to verify)

Answer (score 0):

Node-RED `http-in` nodes requires a `http-response` node to send a response to the client making the request.

Otherwise the client will hang waiting for a reply.

[image: Node-RED flow]